# Get the size of BrowserView from a Webview in Electron

Tags: webview, electron

I'm trying to add the functionality as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32636751/4830093) inside a Webview which is below other elements. Due to this the x and y value it gets are of only the webview itself of course, but the `inspectElement()` method needs to take the x and y value of the window as a whole not just the webview. So I need to be able to get the height of the whole window so I can do a bit of math to offset the values I pass into `inspectElement()`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726409/4830093) when I call `remote.getCurrentWindow()` I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSize' of null
    at click (<anonymous>:3950:147)
    at CallbacksRegistry.apply (<anonymous>:1090:25)
    at handleMessage (<anonymous>:898:21)
    at EventEmitter.ipcRenderer.on.args (<anonymous>:888:7)
    at EventEmitter.emit (<anonymous>:5163:17)
    at Object.ipcNative.onInternalMessage (<anonymous>:3010:15)
```

so It's returning null. Thus that answer doesn't suffice. I can't seem to find anything on StackOverflow or other sites regarding how I could get the height of the window from the webview, or how much the webview is offset from the window itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some sleuthing around and documentation reading I got to this solution.

Here's a function that you pass the webContents into this function and you get access to the BrowserWindow

```
function getBrowserWindowFromWebContents(
  contents: Electron.WebContents
): Electron.BrowserWindow {
  let topContents = contents
  while (topContents.hostWebContents) {
    topContents = topContents.hostWebContents
  }

  return remote.BrowserWindow.fromWebContents(topContents)
}
```

then we have access to [getSize()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#wingetsize)

```
getBrowserWindowFromWebContents(remote.getCurrentWebContents()).getSize()
```

And there we go :)